# max-width not working on div.container-fluid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

[This image 1 is my desired outcome but my result is image 2]

How can you make your png to fit in the div.container-fluid like image 1?

HTML Code:

```
  <!--Footer-->

  <div class="container-fluid w-100 footer" id="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid row">
      <h5 class="col-5 mt-5" id="availableforcontact">
        available for contact on 
        <br>
        saturdays and sundays
        <br>
        EST GMT -05:00
      </h5>
      
      <h5 class="col-3 mt-5" id="contactfooter">
        contact
        <br>
        <p id="location">Manila City, Philippines</p>
        <a href="" id="email">albaalecxavier@gmail.com</a>
      </h5>

      <h5 class="col-3 mt-5" id="socialfooter">
        social
        <br>
        <a href="" id="dribbblelink">dribble</a>
        <br>
        <a href="" id="linkedinlink">linkedin</a>
        <br>
        <a href="" id="twitterlink">twitter</a>
        <br>
        <a href="" id="instagramlink">instagram</a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    **<img src="images/Vector 2.png" alt="" id="redwave" class="w-100">   <!--THIS IS THE PROBLEM-->**
  </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#redwave {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: none;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Just tried your code in an editor—but it's missing some key pieces for the layout, so your issues can't be replicated. Would it be possible to provide additional code?

Answer (score 1):

What is the CSS for the parent div of #redwave?  Unless it has a declared width and height, there would be nothing for #redwave's 100% to calculate against.  If you're wanting to use a percentage of the viewport, you can use vh instead of %, where a width of 1vh == 1% of the viewport's width.  If you're wanting it to take up a percentage of the parent container then you'd need to give the parent container an absolute value for the percentages to be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

These are the styling i wrote.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 50px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  ul li {
  padding: 4px 20px;
  }
}
```

This is the complete code

```css
.wrapper{
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;

}

header{
  height: 120px;
  padding: 4px;
}
header h1{
  font-family: "Amatic Sc";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.btn {
  
  width: 10;
  height: 2px;
    padding: 1.375rem 2.625rem 1.375rem 2.625rem;
    border: 0.125rem solid #B49DF1;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    background-color: #B49DF1;
    color: #fff;
    font: 700 0.75rem/0 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #9876F3;
    border: 0.125rem solid #9876F3;
}




ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 50px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  ul li {
  padding: 4px 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>Novaturient</h1> <!---- Next to this should be the button -->
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="one"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li class="two"><a href="#content">Content</a></li>
                <li class="three"><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                <li class="four"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li class="fice"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```